# Dotcms log showing error

Tags: java, tomcat, dotcms

Hello I successfully managed to deploy my dotcms app in a server but the problem is that i can not start it (the servers runs Tomcat) because there is a problem. Here is what the dotcms.log file shows:

```
[26/02/15 21:58:43:504 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                            7777777   7777       7777     77777777  
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                 OO       777777777  77777      77777    77777777   
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                OOO      77777       777777     77777   7777        
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOOO 7777         7777777   777777   7777        
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO  OOOOO  OOOO  OOOO    OOOO    7777         7777777  7777777    777777     
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         77777777 777 7777     777777   
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO OOOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         777  777 777 7777        7777  
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    77777        777  777777  7777         7777 
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO   OOOO  OOOO   OOO    OOOO     77777       777   7777   7777        7777  
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO      OOOOO    777777777  777   7777   7777  777777777   
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                          Content Management System 
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[26/02/15 21:58:43:510 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[26/02/15 21:58:44:512 EET]  INFO util.OSGIUtil: Felix dir: /home/nikout/domains/saadb.gr/public_html/ROOT/WEB-INF/felix
[26/02/15 21:58:44:514 EET]  INFO util.OSGIUtil: Loading property  felix.auto.deploy.action=install,start
[26/02/15 21:58:44:514 EET]  INFO util.OSGIUtil: Loading property  felix.fileinstall.start.level=1
[26/02/15 21:58:44:514 EET]  INFO util.OSGIUtil: Loading property  felix.fileinstall.log.level=3
[26/02/15 21:58:44:514 EET]  INFO util.OSGIUtil: Loading property  org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning=2
[26/02/15 21:58:44:514 EET]  INFO util.OSGIUtil: Loading property  org.osgi.framework.storage.clean=onFirstInit
[26/02/15 21:58:44:514 EET]  INFO util.OSGIUtil: Loading property  felix.log.level=4
[26/02/15 21:58:44:516 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: /usr/local/java/lib (No such file or directory)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:516 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: /usr/local/java/jre/lib (No such file or directory)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:516 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: /usr/local/tomcat/common/lib (No such file or directory)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:553 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: Problem while creating ZipFile for file: build-classpath
[26/02/15 21:58:44:587 EET]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: Initializing in-memory repository...
[26/02/15 21:58:44:611 EET]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: ...initialized in-memory repository.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:612 EET]  INFO impl.CmisRepositoryContextListener: Initialized Services Factory: com.dotcms.enterprise.cmis.server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl
[26/02/15 21:58:44:616 EET]  WARN util.OSGIUtil: exception while stopping felix!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dotmarketing.util.OSGIUtil.getBundleContext(OSGIUtil.java:193)
    at com.dotmarketing.util.OSGIUtil.stopFramework(OSGIUtil.java:171)
    at com.dotmarketing.listeners.OsgiFelixListener.contextDestroyed(OsgiFelixListener.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4890)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4754)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1251)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:617 EET]  INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: Shutdown event received, executing a clean shutdown.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:661 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[26/02/15 21:58:44:662 EET]  INFO simpl.SimpleThreadPool: Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: http-8080-1
[26/02/15 21:58:44:685 EET]  INFO core.SchedulerSignalerImpl: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[26/02/15 21:58:44:685 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.6 created.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:713 EET]  INFO quartz.DotJobStore: JobStoreCMT initialized.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:714 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.6) 'DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'com.dotmarketing.quartz.DotJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

[26/02/15 21:58:44:714 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler 'DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:714 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.6
[26/02/15 21:58:44:714 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[26/02/15 21:58:44:714 EET]  INFO simpl.SimpleThreadPool: Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: http-8080-1
[26/02/15 21:58:44:722 EET]  INFO core.SchedulerSignalerImpl: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[26/02/15 21:58:44:722 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.6 created.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:723 EET]  INFO quartz.DotJobStore: JobStoreCMT initialized.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:723 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.6) 'DotMarketingQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'com.dotmarketing.quartz.DotJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

[26/02/15 21:58:44:723 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler 'DotMarketingQuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:723 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.6
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO simpl.SimpleThreadPool: Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: http-8080-1
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO core.SchedulerSignalerImpl: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.6 created.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO simpl.RAMJobStore: RAMJobStore initialized.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.6) 'DotMarketingQuartzLocalScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler 'DotMarketingQuartzLocalScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.6
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:727 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:737 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:737 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:737 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:737 EET]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:880 EET]  WARN reindex.ReindexThread: ReindexThread not running (or already shutting down)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:890 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:890 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:891 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:891 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:891 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:892 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:892 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:892 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:892 EET]  INFO license.b: 
[26/02/15 21:58:44:895 EET] ERROR listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: A error ocurred trying to shutdown the ClusterThread.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:897 EET] ERROR listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: A error ocurred trying to shutdown the Cache subsystem.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:898 EET]  INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: Finished shuting down.
[26/02/15 21:58:44:898 EET] ERROR cluster.ClusterFactory: can't remove from cluster
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dotcms.enterprise.cluster.ClusterFactory.removeNodeFromCluster(SourceFile:324)
    at com.dotcms.enterprise.license.LicenseManager$1.run(SourceFile:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[26/02/15 21:58:45:142 EET]  INFO business.CacheLocator: loading cache administrator: com.dotmarketing.business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl
[26/02/15 21:58:45:148 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : default: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:148 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : livecache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workingcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : adminconfigpool: 100
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : blockdirectivecache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categorybykeycache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categorycache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categorychildrencache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categoryparentscache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : companypool: 10
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : contentletcache: 5000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : fileassetmetadatacache: 200
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmslayoutcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmsrolecache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmsrolekeycache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmsuserrolecache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:149 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : fieldscache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:150 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : filecache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:150 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : foldercache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:150 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : hostaliascache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:150 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : hostcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : hostvariablescache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : htmlpagecache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : identifiercache: 50000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : languagecacheimpl: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : navcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : parentpermissionablecache: 10000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : permissioncache: 50000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:151 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : plugincache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : portletpool: 100
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : structurecache: 500
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : templatecache: 500
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : userdotcmscache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : useremaildotcmscache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : userproxycache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : velocitycache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : velocitymenucache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : velocitymisscache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:152 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : versioncache: 50000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : versioninfocache: 50000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : virtuallinkscache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowstepcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowtaskcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : indiciescache: 8
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : publishingendpointcache: 100
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowactioncache: 10000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : logmappercache: 10
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : translatedquerycache: 5000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : csscache: 100
[26/02/15 21:58:45:153 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Disk   : csscache: true
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmsrootrolescache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : identifier404cache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : fieldsvarcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : relationshipcachebyname: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : relationshipcachebyinode: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : propertycache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : containercache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : newnotificationcache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : containerstructurecache: 1000
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Disk   : contentletcache: true
[26/02/15 21:58:45:154 EET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Disk   : velocitycache: true
[26/02/15 21:58:45:160 EET]  INFO cache.H2CacheLoader: Starting Disk Cache
[26/02/15 21:58:45:562 EET]  INFO cache.H2CacheLoader: Disk Cache Started
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JAVA_HOME environmental variable is not set.

```
[26/02/15 21:58:44:516 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: /usr/local/java/lib (No such file or directory)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:516 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: /usr/local/java/jre/lib (No such file or directory)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:516 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: /usr/local/tomcat/common/lib (No such file or directory)
[26/02/15 21:58:44:553 EET] ERROR util.ResourceCollectorUtil: Problem while creating ZipFile for file: build-classpath
```

These lines mean your server's java environment is not set up correctly.

Comment: No i don't think that JAVA_HOME has not been set because in the same server there was anonther java web application which was wokring perfectly...

Comment: the server is using the directadmin web hosting control panel. Do you think that the file .bash_profile should export the JAVA_HOME variable?